# What do you call this type of component? (identifying a USB 3.0 connector)

Tags: pcb, identification, components

[image: part that connects the wires to the PCB]

It's what connects the wires to the PCB. Is it a header? A housing? I tried searching for "down angled USB header surface mount" but couldn't find something close to it.

[image: close up of component]

Comment: The picture is not clear, but looks like a cheap connector that is not USB specific.

Comment: I have added a close up view. So it's just called a connector?

Comment: "Connector" is a generic term that allows the name to be correct without actually being helpful.   Also, "right angle" is a better term for "down angle", although that term by itself won't get you to the answer.

Comment: Maybe "right angle shrouded header".  The exact spacing between the pins can help narrow the search. For example are they 2mm spacing or 2.54mm spacing or something else?

Comment: Also known as bodge in some circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- These type of connectors are generally called "strips", where the version with pins ("male") is called *header strip*. The version with sockets ("female") is called *socket strip*
- Depending on the number of rows, they are referred to as *single row* or *double row*. (Triple etc exist in rare cases.)
- Single row connectors may be referred to as 1xN or just "N pin", where N is the number of pins. double row may be referred to as 2xN.
- Connectors that are bent 90 degrees are called *right angle*.
- The center to center distance between pins is called *pitch*. This is usually the most important parameter to narrow down the search.
- The connector in your picture is *not* surface mount (SMD/SMT). It is a *through-hole* (TH) connector, since it is soldered in holes, not against a surface. Some connectors may also be *through-hole reflow* (THR), which looks exactly the same but the plastics are suitable to endure a reflow solder process & such connectors typically also come with a removable "pad" where the placement machine can grab and lift the component.
- Pin length and gold plating are other options you might have to specify.

It's a bit hard to tell the specifics from the pic. This looks like single row(?). I *think* the pitch is 2,54mm/0.1'' which is the most common one, but it could also be 2,0mm which is also very common. If there's some manner of plastic mechanics underneath the pins (I can't tell), then it's some board-to-wire version likely specific to a certain manufacturer.

Assuming I'm right so far, you are looking at a 5 pin 2,54mm right angle header strip, through-hole mount. One example of that would be Samtec TSW-105-08-F-S-RA.

Comment: Thank you! It's actually two rows with ten pins.

Answer (score 3):

It's a rectangular connector if you want to find something like this go on digikey or mouser and start narrowing down the search terms. I would start searching for 2x5 conductors ( or 1x5 can't tell from the pic but guessing that USB 3.0 has 9 conductors it's going to need more than five so 2x5) connector with 0.1" pitch (again just estimating but USB connector is 12 mm and that connector is slightly bigger so 0.1 pitch would be about right measure it just to be sure).

### Edit:

With the better picture it appears that it's a 0.1 inch 2x5 header that's right angle (not a connector). It looks like whoever made this soldered the wires right to the header and then soldered the right angle connector to the board.

You also would not want to use said connector for USB 3.0 signals because it most likely destroys the signal integrity of the high speed 3.0 signals, I think it would be difficult for a header like that to carry signals in the +100MHz range, because it's inductance is in the nH range, and the 90Ω impedance needed by the differential pair would not work with that header

Comment: So what is a better alternative if this type of connector destroys the signal integrity?

Comment: NDeLeon you want to look for something specifically designed for USB 3.0 or something that has specified differential impedance and current carrying ability that is compatible with USB 3.0.